# MXGraph.getPrettyXML() not returning dynamically made DOM changes

Tags: xml, database, dom, vertex, mxgraph

I'm trying to persist MXGraph to DB and re generate upon user request. Below is how use user flow is:

- Created HTML for Vertex
- Added vertex (v) to Graph
- select HTML element (v.getElementById())
- modify HTML in (V) vertex
- get XML of graph. Here is Code Snippt im usig to create XML

  > ```
  > var enc = new mxCodec(mxUtils.createXmlDocument());
  > var node = enc.encode(_editor.graph.getModel());
  > var xml = mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node);
  > ```
- persist it to DB

From above, i'm able to HTML of vertex in Step:1 but not after step:3. But, im sure that i'm trying above code snippet after modifying DOM in STEP:3.

Please let me know how to get XML (with dynamically made HTML Changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is not updated in the model if the corresponding DOM element is changed directly. To change the label you can either use `mxGraphModel.setValue` to update and repaint it directly, or install event listeners in the label that update the state of the user object as demonstrated in the [htmllabel.html](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/htmllabel.html) example: